# Create a custom keybind for a notes file on vim

Tags: key-bindings

I want to create a simple notes file and manager it with vim. The system is really easy (plain text rules):

```
- [ ] new entry
- [x] done entry
```

Well, in my `.vimrc` I only have the keybind for add new entries, always on NORMAL MODE:

```
map tn i- [ ]
```

Now, I can't create a keybind for to remplace `- []` for `- [x]`.

How to make it?

P.S.: I found a guide with a commands with similar behavior (but here add the date, useful for someone):

```
" check off a todo item and time stamp it
map gd ^rx: <Esc>:r! date +" [\%H:\%M]"<ENTER>kJA<Esc>$
" create a new todo item
map gt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, I can't create a keybind for to remplace `- []` for `- [x]`

Try the following:

```
nnoremap <leader>x :s/^- \[\]/\- \[x\]/<CR>
```

`<leader>` is by default `\`, so if you didn't make any change to it than put your cursor on the line:

```
- [] hello world
```

and press `\x` to make it:

```
- [x] hello world
```

PS

Using the following you will be able to toggle `x`:

```
fun! ToggleCheckBox()
    if getline('.') =~ '^- \[\]'
        :s/^- \[\]/\- \[x\]/
    elseif getline('.') =~ '^- \[x\]'
        :s/^- \[x\]/- \[\]/
    endif
endfun

nnoremap <leader>x :call ToggleCheckBox()<CR>
```

PPS

I end up using the following:

```
fun! ListToggleCheckBox()
    let rx_bullets = '^\(\s*[-*]\+\s*\)'
    let rx_empty_checkbox = '\(\s*\[ \?\]\+\s*\)'
    let rx_marked_checkbox = '\(\s*\[[Xx]\]\+\s*\)'
    let line = getline('.')
    if line =~ rx_bullets && line !~ rx_bullets.rx_empty_checkbox.'\|'.rx_marked_checkbox
        exe ':s/'.rx_bullets.'/\1\[ \] /'
    elseif line =~ rx_bullets.rx_empty_checkbox
        exe ':s/'.rx_bullets.rx_empty_checkbox.'/\1\[x\] /'
    elseif line =~ rx_bullets.rx_marked_checkbox
        exe ':s/'.rx_bullets.rx_marked_checkbox.'/\1\[ \] /'
    endif
endfun

command! ListToggleCheckBox :call ListToggleCheckBox()

nnoremap <leader>x :ListToggleCheckBox<CR>
```

It does:

- work for the list items starting with `*`, `**(*)`, `-`
- if no checkboxes, it will create empty one
- otherwise it toggles them between `[ ]` and `[x]`

Comment: You dont need the colons prefixing the `substitute` command in your function

Comment: I know. I have just copied it from my command window (`:<C-f>`)

Comment: @MaximKim very helpful have a only one keybind for toggle. Thank you.

Comment: what is `fun!` in this context?

Comment: Function definition @alec

Comment: awesome thanks @MaximKim.  This function would be even more awesome if the cursor position could be maintained (instead of moved back to the `-`... would that be an easy modification to make on this function?

Comment: @alec save cursor position in the beginning, restore in the end. `:h getcurpos()`

Answer (score 2):

I started by suggesting you use the first part of the example command you included since it does what you want but it's totally broken as far as I can tell...certainly it's not compatible with your format. So let's see what we can do.

How would you accomplish the same thing manually if the cursor was somewhere on the line you want to "check"? This is one way: `02f rx`.

- `0` :: Move cursor to the beginning of the line.
- `2f` :: Go forward to the second occurrence of Space
- `rx` :: Change the character under the cursor to 'x'.

These are all done while in "Normal mode". How do we create mappings that are available in Normal mode? With `:nmap`. Or, more precisely, with this variation of that command: `:nnoremap` (see paragraph under `:h :nnoremap` for explanation)...

```
:nnoremap \x 02f rx
```

That's it. Or not. It would be nice to do nothing if there's already a 'x' in the column...or if we're not even on an item type of line...

So here's a better command: `:s/^- \[\zs /x/`

This is a substituion that replaces the character in the "check" column with `x`...but only if there's a space there. Otherwise it does nothing.

The pattern is a little mysterious so here's a breakdown:

- `^` :: match the beginning of the line
- `- \[` :: eat up the three characters that start an item
- `\zs` :: this says that we don't actually do substitution against characters that have been matched before this point
- :: match a space

Mapping it, again with `:nnoremap`, we just need to "hit Enter" (`<CR>`) at the end...

```
:nnoremap \x :s/^- \[\zs /x/<CR>
```

For good measure, here's a mapping to do the reverse ("un-check" an item):

```
:nnoremap \o :s/^- \[\zsx/ /<CR>
```

You can, of course, use whatever unassigned keys you want in place of `\x` and `\o`.

Comment: Thank you @B Layer for the clear info. Now I understood some more about the create mappings system of vim.